# Why does the NULL de-reference in this scenario not cause undefined behaviour

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I came across a piece of code where NULL is typecast to an structure pointer type `(foo *) 0`,and with that pointer de-referencing a member `((foo *)0)->m)` ,and using address of that `&(((foo *)0)->m))` and type casting it to integer to get the memory index of that member with in the structure.`((unsigned int)(&(((foo *)0)->m)))`.

I also see that this macro has specific behavior of giving the offset all the times by giving the index.Please try to help enlighten me.Thanks for the inputs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define  MACRO(m) ((unsigned int)(&(((foo *)0)->m)))

typedef struct
{
int a;
int b;
int c;
int d;
}foo;

int main(void) {
    printf("\n  %d  ", MACRO(c));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you ask exactly the same question again?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc I guess because it's debatable whether the other question should have been closed.

Comment: While I agree that the original question should not have been closed, the correct way would have been to try to reopen the other one, and not to re-ask it again.

Comment: This *is* undefined behavior. You're just (un)lucky nothing bad happens in this specific case, on this specific compiler, with these specific settings.

Comment: @EOF A good answer to this question should detail just why it is UB and preferably suggest a compliant way to get the offset of a struct member.

Comment: or maybe answer the first version (the (suggested) duplicate).

Comment: Please do not post duplicates of your own question, especially since it has a perfectly good answer with a standard reference.

Answer (score 1):

(As explicitly stated in the comments, this answer is not technically correct. However, I retain this answer to give you an intuition of what is happening.)

Taking the address `&x` of any variable `x` does not actually evaluate `x`.

Specifically for pointer `foo *p`, `&(*p)` will not dereference `p`. In fact, `&(*p)` is equal to just `p`.

Your example is just a little bit more contrived, because it does not get the address of some `*p` (in your case, `p = (foo *) 0`), but of one of its members.
However, the argumentation still holds: `p->m` is just a variable, and getting that address never evaluates the variable itself.

You may imagine that, "under the hood", the compiler only computes addresses until you actually *access* the data. And getting an address by `&x` never accesses that data.

Comment: "`&(*p)` will never dereference `p`": any decent optimizing compiler certainly won't do it, but there is nothing that forbids the dereference in principle.

Comment: `&*p` is specified to be equal to `p` even if `p` is `NULL`, but `&p->m` is *not*. This *is* undefined.